# Where can I find this transonic prop airfoil?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

[image]

I am interested in identifying this prop airfoil due to its uncommon high .92% efficiency (the best metal props are closer to 83-87%). I have done an exhaustive search for it. It is labeled **"NACA RML 9 G 06a"**. I do not know where I originally got this plot and therefore have no way to know what "ref 3" is.

It does not appear to be a airfoil number and a google search doe not return any "NACA RML" however I have a library of about 2000 "NACA RM" which refers to NACA **R**esearch **M**emos; perhaps the additional "L" means "Letter(s)".

I can find NACA reports starting with "RM G-10" but no G-9. I have also searched for derivatives of "06a" in an airfoil number. I would appreciate any assistance in identifying this airfoil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label you seek is not an airfoil, it is a [research memorandum](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19930085929) produced at Langley. (**RM L**xxxx) The subject airfoil is NACA 4-(5)(08)-03 and the maximum efficiency from the test as reported in the conclusion was 88% at m0.71, partway down the curve where compressibility effects become adverse.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks... wonderful! I see now the chart label was wrong and that explains why I could not find it.

Comment: @jwzumwalt What, if anything, did you wind up doing with the airfoil? It has interesting performance.

Comment: I am installing a VW engine in a home-built aircraft of my own design and was intrigued by the high speed efficiency. A VW engine is rated at 5000rpm but 3800-4000 (other builders typically run them at ~3400rpm) is more realistic and this puts a 55-60" prop near the speed of sound. This airfoil is about 5% better than similar designs at that speed.

Comment: @jwzumwalt How will you get the airfoil coordinates? It is not numbered like any NACA series with which I am familiar. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: I have pictures of it, and it appears to be similar in design and characteristics to a NACA 10-(5)(08)-03, NACA 4508 or 5508. http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a801420.pdf <br> http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/naca4digit?MNaca4DigitForm%5Bcamber%5D=5&MNaca4DigitForm%5Bposition%5D=50&MNaca4DigitForm%5Bthick%5D=8&MNaca4DigitForm%5BnumPoints%5D=81&MNaca4DigitForm%5BcosSpace%5D=0&MNaca4DigitForm%5BcosSpace%5D=1&MNaca4DigitForm%5BcloseTe%5D=0&yt0=Plot